# How to cancel bootstrap CSS left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to give to `.dropdown-menu` class of bootstrap-only right position, but in `bootstrap.css` it has `left:0;`, and the dropdown `<ul>` stretches to full length, because it has `right:0;` and `left:0;`.

How can I cancel `left:0` or override it without changing the `bootstrap.css`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply override it to its default value in your own custom CSS:

```
body .dropdown-menu{
    left: auto; //default value
}
```

You might need to adjust the specificity of the selector so the style gets applied.

Comment: @Nikgaru MDN has great docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left Refer to "initial value"